# Rider IDE can't run project Xamarin.iOS on iPhone device

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, rider

I have two distinct problems here,
The first, is that. I downloaded and installed Rider IDE on a new macOS with Xcode 12, and I started Rider with my Xamarin.iOS project. once I restored nuget packages and ran the project on an iphone device, I got this error

> Failed to install application on device iPhone: error HE0004: Could
> not load the framework 'IDEKit' (path:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/IDEKit):
> dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/IDEKit,
> 1): Library not loaded:
> @rpath/DVTAnalyticsKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTAnalyticsKit
> Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
> Reason: image not found

So, I went online for a solution, and found that this was due to the fact that Xamarin.iOS pakcages are old.
I just decided to install VS for mac, to have both IDEs and update Xamarin.Ios and android packages at the same time.

After doing this, the earlier problem disapeared, but I have a new problem which I couldn't find a solution that worked for me yet.
I get this error when I launch on real device:

> /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mlaunch
> --devname "iPhone" --killdev com.youscribe.youscribe.app --launchdev
> /Users/damien/Desktop/WorkProjects/App/iOS/MobileApp.Ios/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone11.8-14.2/MobileApp.Ios.app
> --wait-for-unlock
> --argument=-connection-mode --argument=usb -sdk 10 --sdkroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer error MT0026: Could not parse the command line argument '-sdk': Version string
> portion was too short or too long. Parameter name: input

Please can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is a bug in Rider IDE. I have created an issue in JetBrains public issue tracker, feel free track progress and add additional comments there:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-55177

Comment: Thanks, I hope it gets resolved as soon as possible